# Are we passing a new object here?

Tags: android, object

From an Android tutorial:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

===================

1. `Bundle savedInstanceState` <--- are we passing here a new Bundle object or an existing one?
2. Why are we calling `super.onSaveInstanceState` in the end vs usually at the beginning?

sorry if they are dumb questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Same object, just with two additional key/value pairs added.
2. In this particular case, it does not likely matter if you call the parent method (onSaveInstanceState) before of after your code in the derived class implementation. It just matters that you DO call it somewhere in there so that the parent class (presumably Activity) can store its own state.  Unless the code in the child method has any bearing on the behavior of the parent method, I usually call the parent method as the first line of such methods.  I suppose it could matter if the parent class also stored identical key names called STATE_SCORE and STATE_LEVEL into the Bundle. Which ever putInt call that happened last would win.

Comment: To the second point i would like to say that you're right that you can place it wherever (important is that you're calling super). But by convention super should be called always at the beginning for the "clean" readability of code.

Comment: I know it is the same object. I guess I wasnt clear. I mean here: public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)..... Ok, I think I got it. It is a new object, but it contains saved state information duh...

Comment: @Geralt - agreed. I was updating my answer with similar comments before I saw your comment.

Comment: @EduardToronto - I'm not sure if I understand your question. I think you are asking if Bundle was freshly allocated before the call to onSaveInstanceState or if there was already data kept in it?  I don't know, but I'm not sure why it matters.

Comment: I think I know why it is called at the end of the code - because it has to now save a new state as it has been changed by saving games state.

Comment: I figured that out for this particular case. But my initial question was when you pass an object like this: public void functioName(className objectName)  <--- is objectName a newly created object or an existing object?

Comment: @EduardToronto - Always an existing object.  Technically all java method parameters are "by value". But variables that are objects (instances of a class) are always references. So passing an object to a method is passing an existing reference (by value).

Comment: @selbie while it is generally better to call the parent method at the beginning of a derived method, in the case of `onSaveInstanceState`, it should always be called at the end. The parent method does the actual saving of the modified bundle. Look into the source code for [`Activity#onSaveInstanceState()`](http://goo.gl/BBJdcP).